# Laravel Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection::$name

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Trying to get the names from the 'items' table and ids from the restaurants table. Trying to access using foreach loop but getting the following error message "Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection::$name"

```
public function refreshItems()
    {

        $id3=10;
        $master=10;

       $sqlnames=DB::table('items')->where('restaurant_id','=',$id3)->select('name');
       $sqlids=DB::table('restaurants')->where('id','!=',$master)->select('id');

       foreach($sqlnames as $sqlname)
       {
          echo $sqlname->name;  //**Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection::$name**
       }
foreach($sqlids as $sqlid)
       {
           $sqlid->id;   //**Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection::$name**
       }
}
```

Comment: `DB::table('items')->where('restaurant_id','=',$id3)->get('name')` and `DB::table('restaurants')->where('id','!=',$master)->get('id');`

Comment: it gives error message "Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string"

Comment: why your usgin `echo` ?

Comment: just for a confirmation....

Comment: remove that it try to convert that property onto String

Comment: removed and still getting the same error

Comment: then try `dd($sqlnames)` and check what it is

Answer (score 0):

You're forgetting to actually execute the queries by ending with `->get()`.

```php
$sqlnames=DB::table('items')->where('restaurant_id','=',$id3)->select('name')->get();
```

Comment: Tried that but then it gives "Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string" error message